# What does Map<String, Serializable> mean?

Tags: java, serialization

Could someone explain what does `Map<String, Serializable>` mean?  I understand that Map has to have key-value pairs and I am used to seeing `<String, String>` `<Integer, whatever>`, but I have never seen the value to be of the `Serializable` type.  I also understand that `Serializable` is a process of writing object to bytes on disk/network.  But how does this all add up when we use `Map<String, Serializable>`? what does it boil down to?

Can I put any object into the value of type Serializable or it has to be some special object or something else?  Could someone shed some light?

Comment: Your question is puzzling. Do you know what a java interface is ?

Comment: It's just a `Map` of `String` keys to values that implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: This is not a good question. Can you visualize a Map of the type `Map<String,List>`, say all synonyms of a particular word? `Map,String, Serializable>` is no different. Both `List` and `Serializable` are interfaces

Comment: Its a good enough question to be Google's answer to `Map<String, Serializable>`. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I also understand that `Serializable` is a process of writing object to bytes on disk/network. But how does this all add up when we use `Map<String, Serializable>`?

[`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is a Java Interface:

FROM [`API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

- Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface.
- Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
- The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.

> Can I put any object into the value of type `Serializable` or it has to be some special object or something else?

- All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

> Could someone explain what does `Map<String, Serializable>` mean?

It means you will have a `String` key and a value that MUST be an object implementing [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

For example:

```
// valid object for the map
class Bar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // class stuff
}

// not a candidate
class Foo {
    // class stuff
}
```

Then:

```
Map<String, Serializable> myMap = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
Bar bar = new Bar();
map.put("BAR", bar); // this is ok
Foo foo = new Foo();
map.put("FOO", foo); 
// The method put(String, Serializable) in the type HashMap<String,Serializable> 
// is not applicable for the arguments (String, Foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

String is the key, Serializable is the value. It's an object that can be serialized and transported throughout the cluster (using a given SerDe).

Answer (score 2):

`Serializable` is an interface.

What it means is that the values of the map are classes which implements `Serializable` interface

It also means that the static type of an obgect returned by the get() method will be serializable

Answer (score 0):

Map is a thing called a template class (or generic type as used in Java) see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). The Map class takes 2 classes at it's template which can be anything, as long as they match some [perquisites](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Here the Key is just a String and the Value is a class which implements the Serializable. The map class wouldn't be very dynamic if it were to only support classes of (base)class String.